# django-pyodbc-azure - How to use schemas

Tags: django, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I'm using django-pyodbc-azure (https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure) and everything is working fine. However, when I migrate the models, a new schema called 'dbo' is created on the SQL Server database. I want to use an already existing 'sp' schema, is there any way to set the working schema?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, you need to change the default schema for the user your are connecting as. If you're using a SQL Auth user called `django_user`:

```
ALTER USER django_user WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [sp]
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hoped this could be set in Django database settings, but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: It isn't doable without some really ugly hacks! It's best to just create a new SQL Auth user with a default schema.

Comment: This still works in Django 3. Just be aware that changing the schema for the user, followed by applying migrations will result in all your tables being doubles. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Define the db_table under the Meta class of one model as follows:

```
db_table = "[your_schema].[your_table]"
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this answer works? (Before we choose Django and MS SQL for a big project - we have lots of existing tables in different SQL schemas)

Comment: This worked! I've been looking for a workaround for a week, you're a project-saver.

Comment: Note that this only works with schemas in an existing database, `sqlflush` and migrations will still fail.

Comment: This doesn't cover django default tables and library generated tables so I don't think it will solve the problem for most people. I need a way to globally specify a schema for the whole project.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a number of answers don't seem to work any more. Instead, I use the instructions found [here](http://nightlyclosures.com/2019/10/16/working-with-unmanaged-sql-server-in-django-pt-ii/) to set the schema when defining `db_table` such as it goes `schema].[table`. Don't open those square brackets; the important bit is the `].[` between schema and table name.

In your case, you'd need to set:

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'sp].[tablename'
```

Comment: I just cannot believe this is the fix... Not enough enfasis on the M$ hate inside me right now