# Schema in django models besides dbo in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django-models, django-mssql-backend

As I used the SQL Server, Django automatically creates and uses schema `dbo` for any tables.

Is there any way to use existing schema, or force Django to use create another schema instead of all under `dbo` schema.

For example:

```
from django.db import models
import pyodbc
# Create your models here.

class Meetup(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Django has automatically created the table in my SQL Server database

This is my `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': "Django",
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': "DESKTOP-VA0DOPJ",
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'isolation_level': 'READ UNCOMMITTED',  # prevent SELECT deadlocks
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-pyodbc-azure - How to use schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358322/django-pyodbc-azure-how-to-use-schemas)

Comment: Thank you, it is. It can be done with the schema in settings. I found out that it's very useful then.

Comment: Using mssql - not sure if this will be of help. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/
I found this article useful for accessing existing schema - perhaps it could be used to implement new schema. Note that the mssql needs to be added to the `INSTALLED APPS` for the below to work. Works with Django 4.0.5. Then add a meta class below your model class:
`db_table='[schema].[table]'`
https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django/issues/56